# jQuery not available as "$" when using webpack's ProvidePlugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-provide-plugin

I am attempting to use jQuery as `$` in my webpack application's entry `index.js` file, and I am receiving this error when running my application in the browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

This is due to a line in a module I am importing called `bootstrap-switch`, and the line in question is:

`$.fn.bootstrapSwitch = function() {`

So I do not have `$` working as a global variable. I followed instructions on the [ProvidePlugin docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/), as shown below. I also tried the answer provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899466/provideplugin-not-working-with-jquery-webpack) but that didn't work.

This is an abbreviated version of my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js'
    },
    plugins: {
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    }
}
```

And this is my `src/index.js` file:

```
import 'bootstrap-switch';

console.log('I am running');
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

A previous version of this question asked about a build error that was actually an ESLint error. Thank you to @UjinT34 for helping me resolve that problem and focus on the actual error outlined above.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a legacy jQuery plugin wanting to use the jQuery from the `window` — it wanted `window.jQuery`, but yours might be after `window.$`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48690626/5796134

Comment: Aaaaaand there we go! Yes, that was the problem! Very sneaky of the plugin. It uses a self-executing function to initialize, and passes itself `window.jQuery`. Adding in the configuration from the linked question's answer solved this problem. If you'd like to link to it in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm adding this as an answer for future users to find.*

Try adding `'window.jQuery': 'jquery'` to your `webpack.ProvidePlugin()` settings.

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin( {
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        } )
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`no-undef` is a ESlint error. It doesn't know about your webpack setup. You can [specify global variables in esling config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals):

```
{
    "globals": {
        "$": "readonly",
        "jQuery": "readonly"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and you were right, that cleared that ESLint error. But see my "additional note" above: when I run my application, I get an error inside `bootstrap-switch.js`: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined`. And on the line in question, the code is: `$.fn.bootstrapSwitch = function() {`. So it seems like `$` isn't making it as a variable to that module, which I am importing in my `src/index.js` entry point. This is the root point of my question, now that we cleared the ESLint error. Any ideas?